# Romyar Sharifi's notes: Group and Galois Cohomology; ideal vs submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, group-homomorphism

[Lecture Notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/lecnotes.html)

Let $G$ be a group.  Below, the author talks about strictly $\Bbb{Z}$-group rings.

> Definition 1.1.3. 
>   (i) The *augmentation map* is the homomorphism $\varepsilon : \Bbb{Z}[G] \to \Bbb{Z}$ given by 
>   $$
> \varepsilon(\sum\limits_{g \in G} a_g g) = \sum\limits_{g \in G} a_g.
> $$
>   (ii) The *augmentation ideal* $I_G$ is the kernel of the augmentation map $\varepsilon$.

It's intuitively clear to me that this is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module homomorphism, and not a *ring* homomorphism.  Thus any kernel is therefore a $\Bbb{Z}$-submodule.  So why here is it called an *ideal*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on Arnaud's fine (and more general "group ring functor") answer: $\epsilon$ is defined, on generators, by $$\epsilon : \gamma \mapsto 1,$$
for all $\gamma \in G$. In particular, if $g$ and $h\in G$, then $\gamma = gh\in G$, so that by definition $\epsilon (gh) = 1$, $\epsilon (g) =1$ and $\epsilon (h) =1 $.  Therefore  $$\epsilon (gh) =1 = 1\cdot 1 = \epsilon(g)\cdot \epsilon (h),$$
and so on... giving that $\epsilon$ is a ring homomorphism.

By the way, if one starts with the fact that $I_G$ is generated by elements of the form $(g -1)$, then the identity in $\mathbb Z[G]$  $$ h ( g - 1) =  (hg -1)  -(h-1)$$
gives another way to see that $I_G$ is a $G$-module. To verify the 'fact': clearly $g-1 \in I_G$, but on  the other hand,  if $\sum a_g g \in I_G$, we must have that $\sum a_g  = 0$, so that $$\sum a_g g= \sum a_g g - \sum a_g = \sum a_g ( g -1). $$

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration.  I can understand it now.  For some reason it didn't make sense before.  Now it does.  I will get to the second part of your answer after I go over the next part of the notes.

Comment: Arnaud's group ring functor answer is pretty much this: suppose $\lambda \colon G \to H$ is a group homomorphism. Then one also gets a  $\mathbb Z$ homomorphism $\Lambda \colon  {\mathbb  Z}[G]\to {\mathbb  Z}[H],$ defined, at the $\mathbb Z$-module level, by the formula $$\Lambda (\sum_g a_g g) = \sum a_g \lambda (g),$$ i.e., extend $\lambda$ linearly. However, since $\lambda (gh) = \lambda (g) \lambda (h)$, for all $g,h\in G$, one gets that $\Lambda$  also preserves the multiplicative structure of the rings, and $\Lambda$ is a ring-morphism (there is a formal verification to be made!) (cont)

Comment: (cont) - BTW, obviously there is nothing special about the base ring ${\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the augmentation map $\varepsilon$ is really a ring homomorphism, and thus its kernel is really an ideal. A nice way to see this is that $\varepsilon$ is the image of the trivial homomorphism $G\to \{1\}$ under the "group ring" functor. But you can also check it directly, of course.

Comment: This is a little high level for me, but surely I will get to understand it as I progress through the notes.